Sorting columns extracted from a CTE into a variable
I have the following code as part of a stored proc. This part of the code is designed to return the names of columns to be used later in a dynamic PIVOT.
DECLARE @Components NVARCHAR(MAX)='';

WITH CTECols AS (
SELECT cc.strName, cc.dblWeighting
FROM tblStudentComponentInformation sci INNER JOIN tblCourseComponents cc ON sci.lngExamID = cc.lngExamID
INNER JOIN tblCourses c ON cc.lngCourseID = c.lngCourseID
INNER JOIN tblStudents ON sci.strCID = tblStudents.strCID
INNER JOIN tblProgrammeSubstreams ps ON tblStudents.lngProgrammeSubstreamID = ps.lngProgrammeSubstreamID
INNER JOIN tblDegreeProgrammeCodes dpc ON ps.lngDegreeProgrammeID = dpc.lngDegreeProgrammeID
WHERE c.blnResearchProject<>0 AND dpc.blnMScProgramme<>0
)

SELECT @Components=COALESCE(@Components + ',','') 
    +  QUOTENAME(strName)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT strName FROM CTECols) AS Headers

If I simply SELECT the results of my CTE, the results look like this:
SELECT DISTINCT strName, dblWeighting
FROM CTECols




strName
dblWeighting




Literature Review
0.1


Poster Presentation
0.1


Research Paper
0.6


Research Project Performance
0.2



What I want is the list of columns in descending order of weighting, like this:
[Research Paper],[Research Project Performance],[Literature Review],[Poster Presentation]
But what I get is this:
[Literature Review],[Poster Presentation],[Research Paper],[Research Project Performance]
I've tried to sort the data within the CTE:
WITH CTECols AS (
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT cc.strName, cc.dblWeighting
FROM tblStudentComponentInformation sci INNER JOIN tblCourseComponents cc ON sci.lngExamID = cc.lngExamID
INNER JOIN tblCourses c ON cc.lngCourseID = c.lngCourseID
INNER JOIN tblStudents ON sci.strCID = tblStudents.strCID
INNER JOIN tblProgrammeSubstreams ps ON tblStudents.lngProgrammeSubstreamID = ps.lngProgrammeSubstreamID
INNER JOIN tblDegreeProgrammeCodes dpc ON ps.lngDegreeProgrammeID = dpc.lngDegreeProgrammeID
WHERE c.blnResearchProject<>0 AND dpc.blnMScProgramme<>0
ORDER BY dblWeighting DESC
)

And I've also tried sorting the output of the CTE in the statement which follows:
SELECT @Components=COALESCE(@Components + ',','') 
    +  QUOTENAME(strName)
FROM (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT strName, MAX(dblWeighting)  AS Weighting  FROM CTECols GROUP BY strName ORDER BY MAX(dblWeighting) DESC) AS Headers

But neither of these approaches has changed what I get in my @Components variable - the component names are still not sorted in weighting order.
What am I missing?

Using the syntax SELECT @Variable = @Variable + ... FROM is a documented antipattern and should be avoided; it relies on the data engine processing your data in a row by row order, which there is no guarantee of. Instead use string aggregation to achieve the same results. In recent versions of SQL Server that would be by using STRING_AGG, however, in older versions you'll need to use FOR XML PATH (and STUFF) to achieve the same results.

Then, when you swap to an appropriate, non-antipattern, solution is simple: use an ORDER BY clause.

Does this answer your question? Comma separated results in SQL

Thanks @ThomA - managed to use that info to get my query to work.

Thanks to the suggested link from Thom A, I've now changed the code to this, which works:
DECLARE @Components NVARCHAR(MAX)='';

WITH CTECols AS (
SELECT DISTINCT cc.strName, cc.dblWeighting
FROM tblStudentComponentInformation sci INNER JOIN tblCourseComponents cc ON sci.lngExamID = cc.lngExamID
INNER JOIN tblCourses c ON cc.lngCourseID = c.lngCourseID
INNER JOIN tblStudents ON sci.strCID = tblStudents.strCID
INNER JOIN tblProgrammeSubstreams ps ON tblStudents.lngProgrammeSubstreamID = ps.lngProgrammeSubstreamID
INNER JOIN tblDegreeProgrammeCodes dpc ON ps.lngDegreeProgrammeID = dpc.lngDegreeProgrammeID
WHERE c.blnResearchProject<>0 AND dpc.blnMScProgramme<>0
)

SELECT @Components=STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(strName),',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY dblWeighting DESC) 
FROM CTECols


Note that this doesn't handle distinct values (i think), if you have multiple weights per name

Honestly, that DISTINCT probably isn't neded, as I doubt all those JOINs are actually needed. More likely an EXISTS is a far better chioice,

The requirement to produce a list of exams taken requires the join to StudentComponentInformation (exam results), and the need to show only students of a particular type (MSc students) requires the join to students, and then on to programme substreams and finally degree programmes to find out if these students are MSc students. That means that we get several hundred rows (one for each course being taken by a student) hence the need for DISTINCT in my mind. But happy to accept that there's probably a better way that hadn't occurred to me.

i'd go for: cc.strname, max(weighting) as weighting ... group by cc.strName but that's just me, no idea how your data looks

I hope this helps. You can use the ROW_NUMBER function in such cases, it's extremely useful.
    SELECT @Components=COALESCE(@Components + ',','') 
    +  QUOTENAME(strName)
FROM (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT strName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MAX(dblWeighting) DESC) AS Weighting  FROM CTECols GROUP BY strName ORDER BY MAX(dblWeighting) DESC) AS Headers
ORDER BY Weighting

